# pyright identifies type as Field and not str

Tags: python, pyright

pyright (via coc-pyright in vim and pylance in VSCode) identifies the type of an attribute as `Field` when it is a `str`.

The `CreateKeyRingRequest` is derived from google's `proto.message.Message` and, from the documentation, clearly identifies `parent` as a `str`:

```
 |  Attributes:
 |      parent (str):
 |          Required. The resource name of the location associated with
 |          the [KeyRings][google.cloud.kms.v1.KeyRing], in the format
 |          ``projects/*/locations/*``.
```

**version**

[coc.nvim] coc-pyright 1.1.262 with Pyright 1.1.263

NVIM v0.8.0-dev+3-g3f2e9298b

**code**

```py
from google.cloud import kms_v1
request = kms_v1.CreateKeyRingRequest()                                                                                                                                 request.parent = "test"
```

**error**

```py
[PyRight reportGeneralTypeIssues]
Cannot assign member "parent" for type "CreateKeyRingRequest"
Expression of type "Literal['test']" cannot be assigned to member "parent"...
"Literal['test']" is incompatible with type Field
```

[image: Screenshot of pyright error. Text above.]

Comment: What's your question? If you look at the source you can see it's a proto.Field of type proto.String.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the [source code on github](https://github.com/googleapis/python-kms/blob/ddd76b081f7b3cdcce7672a272640fb4b4704e53/google/cloud/kms_v1/types/service.py#L418):

```
class CreateCryptoKeyRequest(proto.Message):
    parent = proto.Field(proto.STRING, number=1,)
    crypto_key_id = proto.Field(proto.STRING, number=2,)
    crypto_key = proto.Field(proto.MESSAGE, number=3, message=resources.CryptoKey,)
    skip_initial_version_creation = proto.Field(proto.BOOL, number=5,)
```

The docs are calling it a string but in the context that it's a proto field that's a string. Have a read up on the [protobuf protocol](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial). I'm not sure if you're familiar with protobuf but think of it as a more efficient version of SOAP(sending method calls between computers but in binary format rather than xml text). So here the parent property isn't a normal python string, it's a `proto.STRING` in position 1 of the `CreateCryptoKeyRequest` message.

Here's a [bunch of samples of client code](https://github.com/googleapis/python-kms/tree/main/samples/snippets) using the kms library.

Here's a [generated code example](https://github.com/googleapis/python-kms/blob/ddd76b081f7b3cdcce7672a272640fb4b4704e53/samples/generated_samples/cloudkms_v1_generated_key_management_service_create_crypto_key_sync.py) of creating and sending a `CreateCryptoKeyRequest` message.

Here's [a quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python) on the project setup stuff you need to do before running any of this code.